# wget -nd (--no-directories) option not working as expected

Tags: wget, msys

I am using `wget` 1.12 (in msys if it makes a difference) and am trying to mirror a website with the `-nd` option, since the file and folder names on this site are very long. The docs state that

```
‘-nd’
‘--no-directories’
    Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.
    With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current
    directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the
    filenames will get extensions ‘.n’).
```

However, this is not the case. The identically named files keep getting overwritten (think index.html on a large site). How can I get the correct behavior?

P.S. he reason the names are so long is that they are in Hebrew and are being converted to ascii %HH. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps it is a limitation of your filesystem? Are you using NTFS or FAT? What if you do a test run on some files that have no dots in them, so that the added .n adds the only dot?

Comment: I have 1.11.4  I think I got it from gnuwin32 I hadn't heard of msys, it looks similar. gnuwin32 is better known, you could try gnuwin32 But, do you have an example of a site with the problem?

Comment: out of interest does it convert it into different ascii chars or just squares? I find i just get square chars.. there is a good different gui for the cygwin command prompt that shows any unicode char.. maya be mintty.. not sure for cmd.exe

Comment: if you can include the line you are using, and naturally then the site, or a site with the problem, then that'd help.

Comment: I upvoted this initially prematurely, thinking this was a worthwhile question, but since he has actually been back and still not provided a link or a link to another site with te problem, is just a nuisance. If i'd have known, I wouldn't have upvoted it, so it'd be zero if it's lucky, and if i'd have downvoted it, this question would be on -1 which it almost and perhaps does, deserve. Certainly doesn't deserve my upvote that's for sure. I just can't cancel it

Answer (score 0):

Very possibly you also used `-N` (`--timestamping`), which is implied by `-m` (`--mirror`) for example. It effectively disables the preserving of files with the same name. The manual for `-nc` (`--no-clobber`) option says:

> When running Wget with ‘-N’ ... the decision as to whether or not to download a newer copy of a file depends on the local and remote timestamp and size of the file

Usually if there are 2 files with the same name and different path (e.g., `index.html`) they will have different sizes and due to how timestamping works the file will always be overwritten if used with `-nd` option.

You can read more in the documentation for [timestamping](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/html_node/Time_002dStamping.html#Time_002dStamping).