# wget -nd (--no-directories) option not working as expected

Tags: wget

I am using `wget` 1.12 (in msys if it makes a difference) and am trying to mirror a website with the `-nd` option, since the file and folder names on this site are very long. The docs state that

```
‘-nd’
‘--no-directories’
    Do not create a hierarchy of directories when retrieving recursively.
    With this option turned on, all files will get saved to the current
    directory, without clobbering (if a name shows up more than once, the
    filenames will get extensions ‘.n’).
```

However, this is not the case. The identically named files keep getting overwritten (think index.html on a large site). How can I get the correct behavior?

P.S. he reason the names are so long is that they are in Hebrew and are being converted to ascii %HH. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [wget -nd (--no-directories) option not working as expected](http://superuser.com/questions/297965/wget-nd-no-directories-option-not-working-as-expected)